# How to get the bitmap of current layout(For sharing the screen as image) instead of taking screenshot?

Tags: android, layout, view, bitmap

How to get the bitmap of current layout(For sharing the screen as image) instead of taking screenshot? I'm getting the view of layout using following line, 
I can able to get bitmap of this layout but the image is looking as empty(I got blank image). This is my code.

```
View cardShareView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_cad_profile, null);

boolean imageResult=saveImageInLocal(getBitmapFromView(cardShareView), "cad_share.png") == true

public static Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View view) {
    view.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight(),
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    view.layout(0, 0, view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight());
    view.draw(canvas);
    return bitmap;
}

private boolean saveImageInLocal(Bitmap imageData, String filename) {
    String iconsStoragePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/KKMC/";
    File sdIconStorageDir = new File(iconsStoragePath);
    //create storage directories, if they don't exist
    sdIconStorageDir.mkdirs();

    try {
        filePath = sdIconStorageDir.toString() + filename;
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(filePath);

        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fileOutputStream);
        //choose another format if PNG doesn't suit you
        imageData.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 70, bos);

        bos.flush();
        bos.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.w("TAG", "Error saving image file: " + e.getMessage());
        return false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.w("TAG", "Error saving image file: " + e.getMessage());
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Advance Thanks for your response.

Expecting [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0xjy.png)
Bit [I got this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pDK6.png)

Comment: post ur code,may be because of your image loader...

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I created duplicate layout(activity_cad_profile.xml) for take the full view as image which is loaded at the time of main layout is loading. I don't know this is correct way or not. But it's working fine for me.